# vim-LaTeX does not run bibTeX

Tags: compiling, vim, dvi

I'm on a Windows 7 machine, using the most recent version of vim-LaTeX with gVim. With all of the defaults, using `\ll` to compile my document only runs LaTeX once, when it should run multiple times, including a bibtex run. I tried manually adding the line

```
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'dvi'
```

but it does not help. I get no errors from the original LaTeX run.

What's strange is that this setup works fine for me on a different machine. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with a project consisting of lots of separate `.tex` source files. I found that BibTeX is not called when I use

```
\include{other_file}
```

in my main file where `other_file` has new/updated citations. However, if I change this to

```
\input{other_file}
```

bibtex is called correctly. I also noticed in the latex-suite documentation (line 1469 in my version)

> 4. Finally, it will try to see if this file includes other files via the `\input`
>      command. For each such file found, Latex-Suite will repeat the previous two
>      steps stopping at the first file which has either a `\bibliography` command or
>      a thebibliography environment.

I guess it applies only to the `\input` command and not to `\include`.

Answer (score 5):

Looks strange, have you solved the problem?

For me, add the following line into .vimrc solved the problem

```
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,bib,pdf'
```

And my default pdf compileFormat is XeLaTeX

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Windows 7 with Sumatra PDF Viewer and the following settings in my vimrc file work fine:

```
" Compiler and viewer settings
let g:tex_flavor='latex'  
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf =  'SumatraPDF -reuse-instance '
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a few hours debugging vim-latex and found a problem similar to what you have mentioned. Hope this helps other people.

Before vim-latex runs bibtex it searches the .aux file for "\bibdata". If vim is compiled with python, it works fine. If it is not there is a bug that changes the current directory path and hence the search fails. I have corrected this by the following changes. 
In /.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim

Replace the function on line 938 with the following:

```
function! Tex_GotoTempFile()
     let s:origdir = fnameescape(getcwd())
     if !exists('s:tempFileName')
        let s:tempFileName = tempname()
     endif
     exec 'silent! split '.s:tempFileName
     exe 'cd '.s:origdir
 endfunction " }}}
```

This corrects the error. Hope it helps and save others time :).

Answer (score 1):

So, i tried the version of Ex_, but it did not work. However, a small change made it working perfectly.

I am running [Linux Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) with KDE, have [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) installed, and use Document Viewer as pdf viewer.

I added/changed the following in my .vimrc file:

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,bibtex,pdf'
```

Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line into the `.vimrc` or `_vimrc` file.

```
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,bibtex,pdf'
```

this setting works well for multiple compile formats, and it will process `xelatex`, `bibtex`, `xelatex` in sequence.

Comment: can you elaborate on what this does?