# How can I use BibTeX and Biblatex properly using vim LaTeX suite?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, vim, vim-latex

I just stated using the vim-LaTeX-suite. It works quite well, but I fail in using BibTeX. My `vimrc` file is the following. I use an external build order and I think this causes additional problems:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
au BufEnter *.tex set autowrite
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'mkdir -p build && pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode $* && mv build/$*.pdf .'
let g:Tex_GotoError = 0
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'evince'
if has('gui_running')
  set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
  filetype indent on
  let g:tex_flavor='latex'
endif
```

Some googleing gave me the following: I have to use `bibtex build/texfile_without_dot_tex`. How can I include this properly into the `vimrc` file? I would like to configure things so that using `\ll` does all the work, including the Biblatex stuff. I want to have `PdfLaTeX + Bibtex + PdfLaTeX (2 times)`.

EDIT: I am using Biblatex with BibTeX as backend.

Comment: Are you using Biblatex with the BibTeX backend? Or Biblatex with the Biber backend? Or BibTeX? You can't compile with PDFLaTeX -> Biblatex -> PDFLaTeX because Biblatex is just a package you load with `\usepackage{biblatex}`. It can't compile anything. By default, it uses Biber as backend, although BibTeX is supported with some limitations.

Comment: You are right @cfr , I have to clearify: I am using BibLaTeX with BibTeX as backend, but if you know a solution using biber as backend I would use this as well

Comment: So the compilation run you want should be `pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex ...`. Sorry, I don't use vim with LaTeX. (I use vim and I use LaTeX but only rarely together.) So I won't be much help except in suggesting ways to clarify the question :(.

Comment: @cfr Thanks anyway :) It is already a help to phrase it clearer.

Comment: It is a good idea to switch to the newer Biber backend (maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83715/35864) can help). If you must use BibTeX check out [vim-LaTeX does not run bibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95026/35864) for a few hints.

Comment: @moewe I think the reason why I fail is that I want to have the output files in the folder build. And I am not sure how to modify my vimrc file in order to do this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't use vim. Would it be an option not to use the separate build directory? Does it work then?

Comment: @moewe Yes this worked very well. But as far as I can see I have found a solution with the build folder, that works for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a very long time I realised that the problem is the following: `build/*.aux` does not work because the `.bib`-file is not in the folder `build`. As far as I can see exchanging line 6 in the vimrc-code of my question by

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'mkdir -p build && pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode $* && cp *.bib build && cd build && bibtex %:r && cd .. && pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode $* && mv build/$*.pdf .'
```

worked for me.

Kind regards