# Simple bibliography with vim-latex (latex-suite)

Tags: bibtex, vim-latex

I have recently switched from using Overleaf to writing my documents in Vim with the [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) plugin, also known as *latex-suite*. For the most part everything is working smoothly, but I cannot get bibliography/references to work.

To keep it simple I tried to set up bibliography management the same way I did in Overleaf, with BibTex. So I have a file `refs.bib` containing, at the moment, a single entry:

```
@article{berntson2020multi,
  ...
}
```

My `main.tex` file contains a citation

```
\cite{berntson2020multi}
```

and ends with

```
...

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\end{document}
```

Both files are in the same directory. This worked in Overleaf, but when I try to compile via vim-latex I get the error message

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `berntson2020multi' on page 3 undefined on input line 1
84.

No file main.bbl.
[3] (./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

**So, what is a minimal setup to get this to work?** The answers I find online seem to all be for complicated specialized setups; I just want something simple that works.

If it is simpler to use BibLaTeX instead I am open to that as well. I tried for a bit myself but couldn't get it to work.

Oh, and my `.vimrc` contains the following lines related to vim-latex:

```
" Recommended settings for vim-latex
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

" Compile .pdf instead of .dvi
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This is unlikely to be the issue unless you are using an older MikTeX system, but technically speaking `\bibliography{refs.bib}` is incorrect. `\bibliography` takes the file names without file extension. So it should be `\bibliography{refs}`.

Comment: For a bibliography with working citations, your document must be compiled with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX. Overleaf does that for you (it uses the amazing `latexmk` that automatically runs the required tools when required). I don't know what `vim-latex` does. https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1736 suggests `latexmk` is involved, in which case things should in theory work unless there are errors (did you check the `.log` and `.blg` for errors? did you try deleting the auxiliary files?). There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95026/35864.

Comment: Oh, `vimtex` and `vim-latex` are two different things, so what I wrote about `latexmk` might not be true. http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/compiling-multiple.html says `vim-latex` may run LaTeX (and BibTeX) up to five times, but from what I read there it could be that this happens only for DVI output and that you need to enable that for PDF output? So maybe you need `let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'`?

Comment: @moewe is correct on this, while the capability to run/re-run the likes of bibtex as necessary is natively there in `vim-latex` it's enabled by default just for `dvi` target format.  Any target formats `<fmt>` not included in `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` are just run once according to the formats listed in `g:Tex_FormatDependency_<fmt>` and their associated `g:Tex_CompileRule_<fmt>` variables, for `pdf` this defaults to a single `pdflatex` call.

Comment: Thank you both, @moewe and @DaiBowen. I actually found a simple solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95026/vim-latex-does-not-run-bibtex?noredirect=1&lq=1), which makes sense from what you are saying. I put `let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,bib,pdf'` in my `.vimrc` so that bibtex is run when compiling. I suppose the second `pdf` run uses the results from the `bibtex` run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim-latex's mechanism to manage repeated/bibtex/etc compilations is tied explicitly to the file format that is being produced, rather than simply being active or not.

Whether these additional compilation runs are attempted depends on whether `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` (or possibly also any format specified within the associated `g:Tex_FormatDependency_<fmt>`) is found in the `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats`.

By default this is only set to apply to `dvi`, and it is necessary to put `pdf` in there, e.g. by setting `let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'` in vim to only apply multiple compilations to the vim-latex `pdf` format.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229626/265068). That is, I added

```
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,bib,pdf'
```

to my `.vimrc` file. My `.vimrc` now contains the lines

```
" Recommended settings for vim-latex
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

" Compile .pdf instead of .dvi
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,bibtex,pdf'
```

related to vim-latex. This works for me.

Comment: Having the second `pdf` and `bibtex` in `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` is not actually necessary or beneficial, as long as the `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` is in `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` the multiple and bibtex compilations will be run to try and keep that target format accurate viz bibliography, index, labels etc.

Comment: I see, it seems you are correct. Thank you!